# Finding names of a channel array

Tags: discord.js

I want to create an array of strings by getting the names of the channels in a guild, but the methods I've tried haven't worked. This is my code, but the console.log doesn't send the array.

```
if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}command`)){
    var channel_list = Array.from(message.guild.channels.name);
    console.log(channel_list);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to want to use [`Collection.prototype.map()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=map)

#### Discord.js v11.x

```js
console.log(message.guild.channels.map((c) => c.name))
```

#### Discord.js v12.x

```js
console.log(message.guild.channels.cache.map((c) => c.name))
```